# Test to show statsticial change due to an intervention?

Tags: statistical-significance, contingency-tables, odds-ratio

I have a group of 222 test results that were reviewed separately by two interpreters X and Y. Based on their assessment, they were to assign management into 4 categories A, B, C and D.
Then another variable that they were blinded to was revealed to them and again they were asked to assign management into the 4 categories, now with the new information.

So X initially chose A (72%) B (27%), C (2%) and D (0%) and Y initially chose A (72%), B (22%), C (4%) and D (3%)
After the blinded variable was revealed, X changed their answers and it became A (77%), B (18%), C (5%) and D (0%) and Y became A (74%), B (18%), C (8%) and D (0%)

I want to show the difference the variable had on X's choices and if that is statistically significant (p<0.05) and the same for Y. Then I want to evaluate if there was a difference in the pre and post variable results between X and Y and what it was driven by. My hypothesis is that the variable will make definite changes to A and more so for the Y reviewer

I thought doing multiple contingency tables might be the best thing to do? i.e. I did 2x2 table of X showing numbers of A or not A pre and post the variable and repeated this for each of B,C and D. Is this an appropriate thing to do? Or would it be better to show an Odds Ratio i.e that with the variable, the odds of doing something increased by such and such an amount? How would one do this.